# How can we know which .so file a particular cpp file is in? (in Android rom)

Tags: android, c++, decompiler

I found some modified code in a cpp file in android to protect smartphone from stagefright vulnerability.
I want to change it with original cpp file and rebuild to a new android ROM file.

The problem is,

I downloaded an android factory image from google developer forum and
I unpacked it with android kitchen tool.
Now I can see its contents but I couldnt find the file, I wanted to modify, "/media/libstagefright/MPEGExtractor.cpp".

There are only some .so files in system/lib/ folders.
I heard it's almost impossible to decompile those .so files.

I tried googling to find out which .so files have "MPEGExtractor.cpp", so that I would be able to compile some files including that cpp file into a .so file, and change it, and rebuild it a new ROM.. but I couldn't find out.

What should I do to rebuild it with some code to be changed?

Thank you for reading

Comment: libstagefright has already been patched. If you're building from AOSP, you're not going to be vulnerable anyway.

Comment: Do you need to know the CPP file specifically or are you searching for a specific function?

Comment: I highly recommend rebuilding the project.  Otherwise, you may want to create some DLLs so you don't have to rebuild everything.

Answer (score 0):

SO(Shared Object) are files that are compiled from source. By definition they do not contain the symbol information you are asking for.